# Cannot construct pointer from 0 when passed through a function template

Tags: c++

Let's say I have an arbitrary type: `struct Bar {};`. And I want to construct a `Bar*` from 0, I can do that explicitly:

```
Bar* b = 0;
```

I can even do it implicitly through a function call:

```
void foo(Bar* b) { Bar* x = b; }

foo(0);
```

But that ability disappears when I pass the 0 through a function *template*:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t) {
    Bar* x = t;
}

foo(0); // error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Bar*’
```

Why not? What's special about the other two formulations that no longer applies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero is special. Zero as a constant can be assigned to a pointer to represent the null pointer. But you can't assign an int to a pointer in general without a cast.

Answer (score 6):

Initializing a pointer to `0` is different from type deduction for `0` (i.e. `int` literal) to `Bar*`. Thus the error.

For compliance with the [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standard use the `nullptr` keyword instead of the plain `0` literal to unambigugate the types.
Also note for pre-c++11 standard implementations using the good old `NULL` macro might work better than the plain `0` literal, since `NULL` usually expands to `(void*)0` which also makes a difference when working with templates and pointers to template parameter types.

For your (slightly wrong) template function definition

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T* t) {
      // ^^ Note!
    T* x = t;
 // ^ Note!
}
```

The following code should compile with C++11 as

```
foo(nullptr); // C++11
```

and Pre C++11 as

```
foo((void*)0); // NULL didn't work for IDEONE GCC 4.8 and including 
               // <cstddef>. I'd expect it to expand to (void*)0, but 
               // it seems expanding to (int*)0 ?!?
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to ensure that the passed pointer type is compliant to some base class pointer type, you'll need an explicit cast:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T* t) {
    Bar* x = static_cast<Bar*>(t);
}
```

But then you'll have to pass a concrete pointer type to the function:

```
class Derived : public Bar
{
    // Blah!
};

Derived* x = 0;

foo(derived);
```

`static_cast` won't work with `void` pointers!

Comment: Please also mention that nullptr should be used for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're calling my function incorrect, I very intentionally am constructing a Bar* from a T.

Comment: @Barry Then ypu'll need a `static_cast` maybe! The reason for the error still is that type deduction from a plain int to a whatever typed pointer doesn't work without casting.

Comment: @g-makulik I don't want to cast - I want to construct.

Comment: @Barry Then you're on the wrong path anyway!! You cannot construct an instance just by assigning a pointer, you'll need either `new()` or an existing reference to construct a copy!

Comment: @Barry ... and why you're accepting an answer that doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @g-makulik He did answer my question. Your answer is littered with all these statements about how my use-case is wrong and how I need to use static cast. That is absolutely not an answer to my question. And no, I do not need new in my use-case either, but I appreciate that faulty assumption too. Good day, sir.

Comment: @Barry So since a statement `Bar* x = t;` doesn't **construct** anything, but just tries to interpret a pointer assignment: From this point of view your question misses some crucial requirements for the _'use case'_ you described. And it won't be possible to **construct** some instance from a `nullptr` though. Then at least explain what's your working solution ...